# Passing an associative array to PHP

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, associative

I have an associative array in JavaScript that looks something like this:

```
data = { 1: "DA", 2: "DA", 3: "NE", 4: "DA", 5: "NE", "ime": "Kojo" }
```

I've converted it using jQuery.param(data) and I got something liek

```
1=DA&2=DA&3=NE&4=DA&5=NE&ime=Kojo
```

Don't mind the values

How can I pass that to PHP to ajax using `$_GET`? And how can I receive it in PHP afterwards, still as an array? Thanks

Comment: One little correction : "via ajax", not "to ajax"

Comment: you can call to you php script like `http://YOUSERVER/FILE.php?1=DA&...` and in php you can `echo $_GET['ime'];` for example

Comment: The thing is that data gets generated along the way so I've got no idea which values would be there. That's why I need it passed as an array

Answer (score 1):

You could convert the object to a string using `JSON.stringify` and pass it as one parameter. On the PHP side, you can use `json_decode` to convert it back to an array.

```
// JS
$.get('endpoint',{data: JSON.stringify(data)});

// PHP
$data = json_decode($_GET['data']);
```

You could also pass in the raw object as data. As far as I remember, jQuery serializes it into a flat string structure. On the PHP side, it's automatically converted into an associative array.

```
// JS
$.get('endpoint',{data: data)});
// endpoint?data[1]=DA&data[2]=DA&data[3]=NE&data[4]=DA&data[5]=NE&data[ime]=Kojo

//PHP
$data = $_GET['data'];
```

Comment: What exactly am I passing as data in the second method you described?
Should I make a variable like var strData = $.get('endpoint',{data: data)});,
or what?

Comment: @AleksaKojadinovic `data` there is the `data` in your post. `$.get` does a ajax GET request.